# Finding every representation of the Lorentz Group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For some time I've been trying to truly understand how to find all the finite-dimensional representations of the proper orthochronous Lorentz Group $SO(1,3)$, the part connected to the identity. I have found no single reference that approach it from start to finish (the closest being the Wikipedia article) and although there are good books on Representation Theory which cover everything needed, I'm not sure I have grasped the whole thing. My current line of thought is the following (keep in mind that this is from a physicist point of view):

**1)** The group is non-compact, which means that there are no finite-dimensional unitary representations; and non-simply-connected, which means that there is no guarantee that there exists a ('global') representation of $SO(1,3)$ for each representation of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ (we must look for its projective representations or regular representations of its universal covering).

**2)** We start complexifying the algebra: $\mathfrak{so}(1,3) \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\mathbb{C}$. This is harmless since we can canonically extend every representation of an algebra to a unique complex-linear representation of its complexification; and, on the other way, we can restrict every representation of an algebra to a representation of the appropriate real form.

**3)** Then we may check a well-known change of basis which is enough to convince ourselves that $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\mathbb{C} \cong \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$ and, since the extension of the vector space of traceless hermitian matrices by the addition of traceless anti-hermitian matrices gives us the space of traceless complex matrices (or the other way around, in the math convention), we also have $\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C} \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{C}$.

**4)** This is nice because  $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2) \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is simply connected and we do know how to find its every irreducible represention by the highest weight construction.

**5)** Since $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is simply connected, we know that the isomorphism between $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\mathbb{C} \cong \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$ imply the existence of an isomorphism between the corresponding groups and, also, representations.  *I.e.*, having found every irrep. of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, we have found every irrep of $SO(1,3)$.

**6)** We then use the Weyl unitarian trick to show that every representation of the group corresponding to $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$ is completely reducible (we could also have evoked a similar result directly for semisimple Lie Algebras, which is the case of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$), since it is compact and, by isomorphism, extend this property to $SO(1,3)$, ensuring that we have found every representation of it.

Besides being possibly poorly phrased and way imprecise, does the above make sense? What are the misconceptions? How to fix the line of thought above while keeping the same language/strategy?

Comment: This could do with some focus.

Comment: Several times you say that certain Lie algebras are simply connected. I would think that is a property of Lie groups, not algebras.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg would it be well-defined to say that a Lie Algebra is semisimple if the corresponding Lie Group is?

Comment: Simply-connected*

Comment: No, because a Lie algebra in general does not have a unique corresponding Lie group. In fact, almost all the standard examples have one corresponding Lie group which is simply connected, and several others which are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is some confusion here both between Lie group and Lie algebra properties and also about passing back and forward between the complexification and real forms.

First things first, as Torsten says, simply connected is a property that is important for Lie groups **not** for Lie algebras. If we want to get technical, any Lie algebra is simply connected since it is just a vector space. The importance of simply connectedness in Lie theory is that a Lie algebra has several Lie groups corresponding to it. There is only one among these groups which is simply connected and crucially for every representation of the Lie algebra there is a corresponding representation of the simply connected groups. Others of these groups will also have some of these representations (they will all have an adjoint representation for example) but the simply connected one guarantees a one-to-one correspondence.

So talking about Lie algebra representations is "equivalent" to talking about simply-connected Lie group representations.

So then as you say you can learn about the representations of $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ by looking at its complexification $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathfrak{so}_4 = \mathfrak{sl}_2\oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2$. Now, since you are a physicist, we should be careful about different naming conventions here. For every representation of a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ on a complex vector space $V$ there is a corresponding representation of each of real form $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{R}}$ on the same **complex** vector space $V$ (just restrict the representation) and going the other way is similarly easy. Note these are not what physicists call real representations (but if we can find a real subspace $V_{\mathbb{R}} \leq V$ preserved by the representation we can make one of those). So there is a one-to-one correspondence again between (complex) representations of $\mathfrak{g}$ and of $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Note carefully that this does **not** give us a one-to-one correspondence of representations between representations of $SO(3,1)$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong Spin(3,1)$. Their Lie algebras are isomorphic (viewing the second one as a real group/algebra) but only one of them is simply connected ($SL(2,\mathbb{C})$). So every representation of $SO(3,1)$ corresponds to one of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ but not the other way round. The simplest examples of these missing representations are the spin representations. Just as in the definite case ($SO(4)$) there are two half-spin representations here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I do understand that it makes no sense to call the algebra (a vector space not even equipped with a topological structure - in principle) 'semisimple', that was an error and an abuse while writing the question. I don't quite understand what was my mistake about going back and forth between complexifications. And about the last point: so I guess we need to make a separate remark, that we need all *projective* representations of $SO(1,3)$, and this is what forces us to consider *every* irrep. of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. Is it correct?

Comment: I did mention it in point 1), but thought that the consequences was contained within the other points.

Comment: @GaloisFan Again I think you mean simply connected there. My point about the complexifications is that we need to be slightly careful about what representations we have found. E.g. does $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ have a representation on a 2-d real vector space because $\mathfrak{sl}_2\oplus\mathfrak{sl}_2$ has a 2-d complex representation or does it only have a complex one? Also $\mathfrak{so}(3,1) = \mathfrak{sl}_2$ (as real Lie algebras) but it is definitely not true that $\mathfrak{su}_2 \oplus \mathfrak{su}_2= \mathfrak{sl}_2$: the left hand side is compact but the right isn't

Comment: One thing I should also make clear. What we are achieving here is a correspondence between representations not an isomorphism. The representations of $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ are not isomorphic to those of $\mathfrak{su}_2\oplus\mathfrak{su}_2$ or $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2$. Instead they are just in a natural one-to-one pairing.

Comment: I did mean simply-connected xD. I'll think about what you are saying and perhaps follow-up with a question here later. Thank you very much!

Comment: I still have several confusions, but I suppose it's not appropriate to discuss them in the comments. I'll just ask about one thing: it seems my greatest source of misconceptions is my point **5)**. We have found an isomorphism between the complexification of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ (whose group's reps. I wanna find) and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{C}$. We know that $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is simply-connected, so that a morphism $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{C} \to \mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\mathbb{C}$ implies a morphism $SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \to SO(1,3)$.

Comment: Starting from this, how do we find every projective irreps o $SO(1,3)$?

Comment: So there is indeed a group homomorphism $\phi:SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \to SO(3,1)$ effectively projecting onto a quotient by part of the centre. You can construct a projective representation then by $\rho(g) := [\hat{\rho}(\hat{g})]$ where $\hat{\rho}$ is the $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ rep, $\hat{g}$ is an element in the preimage of $g$ under $\phi$ and the square brackets represent projection from $GL(V)$ to $PGL(V)$. You can find this on [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation#Projective_representations_of_Lie_groups)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again! I'm still trying to understand some things. Based on your last comments, I have some doubts: **1)** Is it not true that  $\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C} \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{C}$ ??  **2)** You said that $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ has a 2d complex rep. Wouldn't it need to be 4d?

Comment: @GaloisFan 1) That is true (where the last $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is viewed as a real Lie algebra. 2) It has 2 2D complex irreps. One for each $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$. Basically when we have a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_2$ we can make reps by taking a rep of  $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and letting $\mathfrak{g}_2$ act trivially on it. From the perspective of $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ these are the 2 (complex) half-spin reps .

Comment: what does it mean to view $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ as a real Lie algebra? Is it about taking the scalars from a real field? Why does the isomorphism only holds if we view it as a real Lie Algebra?

Comment: @GaloisFan it is not that the isomorphism doesn't hold but that complexification doesn't make sense otherwise. It is exactly restricting our scalars to the real numbers. Thus it is a 6-dimensional real Lie algebra